# Find the green's function for $y'' -2xy' = f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Usually given a Sturm-Liouville Problem $$[p(x)y']'+[q(x)+\lambda r(x)]y = 0 $$ and then proceeded to find the Green's function.

However I have found the following problem and I am a bit lost on how to approach it. I know that to find my Green's function I can define my characteristic equation, then from it I obtain my general solution. But for this problem I am confused. Maybe I need to use the method of integrating factors? How would I do it?

Problem: 
Consider the boundary value problem: $$u''-2xu'=f(x)$$ $$ 0 < x < 1$$ with boundary conditions: $$ u(0) = u'(1) = 0 $$

Find the Green's function or explain why there isn't one.

Would appreciate the help!

Comment: Please check the operations, in the title it is a sum, in the text a difference.

Comment: It is a minus sign. I made a mistake in the title.

Comment: Integrating factor is $e^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the Green function is
$$
G(s,t)=\frac{y_1(\min(s,t))\cdot y_2(\max(s,t))}{W[y_1,y_2](s)}
$$
where $y_1$ satisfies the left boundary condition and $y_2$ the right, both solutions of the homogeneous equation. $W(s)=y_1(s)y_2'(s)-y_1'(s)y_2(s)$ is the usual Wronskian.

With 
\begin{align}
y_1(x)&=\int_0^xe^{s^2}\,ds,\\ 
y_2(x)&=1\\
W(s)&=-e^{s^2}
\end{align}
we get
$$
G(s,t)=-e^{-s^2}\int_0^{\min(s,t)}e^{v^2}\,dv
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$u''-2xu'=f(x)$$
Let $u'=v$
$$v'-2xv=f(x)$$
The solution is
$$v(x)=u'=e^{x^{2}}\Big(c_{1}+\int^{x}_{0}f(y)e^{-y^{2}}dy\Big)$$
Applying the boundary condition $v(1)=0$ we get
$$c_{1}=-\int^{1}_{0}f(y)e^{-y^{2}}dy$$
Thus
$$v(x)=u'=e^{x^{2}}\int^{x}_{1}f(y)e^{-y^{2}}dy$$
$$u(x)=c_{2}+\int^{x}_{0}e^{z^{2}}\int^{z}_{1}f(y)e^{-y^{2}}dydz$$
And due to the second boundary condition $c_{2}=0$, thus
$$u(x)=\int^{x}_{0}e^{z^{2}}\int^{z}_{1}f(y)e^{-y^{2}}dydz$$

Comment: That does not quite show what the Green function is. For that you need to to transform the integrals so that you can extract $G$ from $$u(x)=\int_0^1G(x,y)f(y)\,dy.$$

Comment: Interchange orders of integration and you've got the Green function formulation.